# 正式版として、2023年度のモデレーター選挙を行います！

Tags: 討議, 選挙

**要約**：スタック・オーバーフローでは、**2023年 5 月 17 日**にモデレーター選挙の立候補を開始します。

今後の予定：

- 5 月 10 日に、立候補者への質問をコミュニティから募るための投稿がメタへ投稿されます。
- 5 月 17 日以降、立候補ができるようになります。ひとつ前の週に集められた質問たちの中から上位のものが編纂され質問リストとなり、モデレーター候補者の皆さんが答えられるように提示されます。
- 既存のモデレーターの皆さんは、そのままモデレーターであり続けるためには立候補する必要があります。
- 5 月 24 日、もし 4 名以上の立候補者がいれば、実際の選挙が始まります。もしそうでなければ、立候補の期間が 1 週間延長されます。それでも立候補が 4 名集まらなかった場合、正式版としての選挙はキャンセルされ、今回は暫定版選挙とみなされます。今回の選挙立候補者が（既存のモデレーターの皆さんだと継続、そうでなければ新規に）モデレーターとして任命されます。これは、サイトモデレーターの総数を最大にするためです。（暫定版モデレーター選挙プロセスの詳細については、[Meta Stack Exchange の投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)を参照してください。）（また、場合によっては[立候補を取り消す](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year)こともありますが、ほぼ起こることは無いでしょう。）
- 選挙が完了した場合、6 月 1 日（立候補が延長された場合は 6 月 8 日）に、メタに結果が投稿されます。

もし何か選挙の進め方について質問があれば、この投稿に回答として投稿してください。

<sub>この翻訳は、日本時間JSTの日付を使用しています！選挙ページに自動で表示されるUTC時間ではありませんので、どうぞお気をつけくださいませ。</sub>

Comment: 「選挙プロセスの詳細については、Meta Stack Exchange の投稿を参照してください」としてリンクされている投稿は、日本語版でいうところの暫定モデレーター選挙の話について書かれていませんか？例えばリンク先の投稿には「Current moderators will not be required to nominate themselves—they will continue as moderators unless they ask to step down.」とありますが、これは本投稿の説明と矛盾しているように思いました。

Comment: @unarist ご指摘に感謝します！今回 SpencerGさんが書いてくださったものを忠実に訳すように編集いたしました。意訳と部分的な直訳が混在してしまったこと、そして私の理解が間違っていたことが原因でした。大変申し訳ありません！