# 2023 年度 コミュニティ・モデレーター選挙の結果

Tags: 討議, モデレーション, 選挙

2023 年度 スタック・オーバーフロー [モデレーター選挙](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/2) は十分な候補者人数に至らなかったためキャンセルされました。

その結果、立候補くださった方をこのたび任命することとなりました：

[image: mjy]

近日中に、@mjyさんが [モデレーションチーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)に加わる予定です。ボランティア活動へのご貢献を感謝し、もしもモデレーターとしての仕事を覚えるためのアドバイスや応援メッセージなどがあればぜひこちらにご共有くださいませ。これからもスタック・オーバーフローのコミュニティをより良い方向へ導くために、ご協力をよろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: mjy さん、よろしくお願いします！

Comment: FYI: mjy さんと交代で、Yuki Inoue さんはご退任となりました。Yuki Inoue さんは be nice なモデレーションについて毎回かっちりとしたご意見をくださり、とても参考にしていました。Yuki Inoue さんありがとうございました。

Answer (score 5):

任命いただき、ありがとうございます。8月22日に[Moderator Agreement](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)に同意し、モデレーターになりました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

---

今回の選挙プロセスには例外が多く、事情を追っていない方には不可解な点が有るかと思いますので、私に可能な限りを説明いたします。

- 選挙終了（5月30日）から結果の発表までが長かった:
  たまたま選挙直後に[「Moderation Strike」](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an)が始まり、その影響を受けました。その時点で私はモデレーターでは無かったので、事情は定かでは有りませんが、通常であれば直ぐに結果が発表されるはずで、次回はおそらくそうなるでしょう。
- 選挙が不成立でもモデレーターが任命された:
  これは選挙ページや[告知の投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3880/)には説明が有りませんでしたが、[事前の予告](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3875/)にて説明されていました。今回は通常の選挙から「暫定版選挙」のプロセスに推移し、立候補者全員（nekketsuuu さんは既にモデレーターですので継続）が任命されました。
- Yuki Inoue さんの退任:
  これは私には予想外で残念でしたが、モデレーターが一定期間非アクティブであると行なわれる[ほぼ自動のプロセス](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337431/)のようです。Stack Overflow本家（英語版）などではモデレーターも志望者も多数おり、こういった事をカジュアルに行なっても問題が無いのだと思います。Yuki Inoue さんは日本語版において貴重な存在であり、我々ユーザーから連絡して戻っていただくという選択肢もあるとは思いますが、本業がお忙しいと思いますので、私からそういった無理のお願いはしないことにしました。

Yuki Inoue さんの今までのご貢献に感謝いたします。今後、ユーザーとしてのご意見などありましたら遠慮なくぶつけていただければと思います。

Comment: おめでとう！ (私は日本語のネイティブユーザーではありません、ごめんなさい。)